# Can I put an Alarm inside another Alarm? Can a service stop an Alarm?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, intentservice

I'm making an App that once a day connects to a FTP server. Now, for that I use AlarmManager and IntentService and it works fine on normal conditions.

Now say theres no Internet when the Alarm fires and I want it to try again every 15 minutes until it connects and finishes the task successfully. How can I do that?

Is it possible to create an alarm that creates an alarm?
Can the service stop the alarm once the task is completed successfully?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
startActivity(intent);
```

Or use an Activity and send to background

```
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
moveTaskToBack(true)
```

Comment: Didn't get it. Activity and Intent are not repeated after a preset time like Alarms are. How would I use this to start a task once a day and make it repeat itself every 15 minutes until successful completion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing a possible solution.

In the alarm I generate a While clause that if there is no Internt will wait for some time.

Once Internet is connected the while loop ends and it continues normally starting my service.